# Not able to create java calendar object in Node.js using java utilities in node.js

Tags: java, node.js, node-java

This is my piece of code to create java calendar object in Node.js using node-java module.

```
var java = require("java");
java.classpath.push("commons-lang3-3.1.jar");
java.classpath.push("commons-io.jar");
java.classpath.push("common-util.jar");

var vehId = java.newInstanceSync("java.lang.Integer", 922);
var lattitude = java.newInstanceSync("java.lang.Double", 8.6717136);
var longitude = java.newInstanceSync("java.lang.Double", 76.8168311);
var time= '';

var Calendar = java.newInstance("java.util.Calendar", function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Error: '+err);
    return;
   }

  else {
    console.log("Result: "+result);
    time = Calendar.getInstance();
  }
});

var args = {
              vehicleId : vehId,
              lat : lattitude,
              lan : longitude,
              packetTime : time
};
console.log(args);
```

This is the error got when tried to execute the program.

```
Error: Could not find method "java.util.Calendar()" on class "class java.util.Calendar". No methods with that name.
```

Couldn't create calendar object using `java.newInstance()` or `java.newInstanceSync()` functions.

Comment: Farid, can we able to create calendar object in Node.js, If yes can you please explain which module should we use.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create calendar object in node.js. Use 'node-calendar' module. [https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-calendar](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-calendar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var Calendar = java.newInstanceSync("java.util.GregorianCalendar");
```

It will create a default GregorianCalendar using the current time in the default time zone.